# Mongodb How do I sum and group

Tags: mongodb, sum, group

I want to know what the population of Europe is

This is one of [my object in my mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYMsb.png)

When I use this line

```js
db.landen.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    subregion: "Eastern Europe",
    count: {
      $sum: $population
    }
  }
}])
```

I get the following error code: `population not defined`

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text for source data. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 2):

`$population` is not a variable, wrap it in quotes

This snippet will match all Europe countries only and then group them by subregion and count population.

```js
db.landen.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    region: "Europe"
  },
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$subregion",
    count: {
      $sum: "$population"
    }
  }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, now it's says the field region must be a accumulator object

Comment: Is the goal to sum the population of only europe or each "subregion"?

Comment: It's the goal to have the population of only eastern Europe.

Comment: Now I will figure out only to get the Eastern part but thanks, have a nice day

Comment: You can just change the `$match` from `region: "Europe"` to `subregion: "Eastern Europe"`